# PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `dandelion`

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Whenever I try to migrate my database to Laravel I have that problem.

I tried several options but none of them seem to work. 
Thanks in advance!

Users table:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('avatar',100)->nullable();
        $table->string('country',100)->nullable();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Create Products table:

```
enter code here:

 Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name', 100);
        $table->decimal('price', 8, 2);
        $table->string('image', 100);
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Add Category id to Column Products:

```
enter code here:
Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')->nullable();
      $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
    });
}
```

Interest Table:

```
enter code here:
  Schema::create('interests', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name',100)->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Brands table:

```
enter code here:
     Schema::create('brands', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Add Brand id to Products Table:

```
enter code here:
   Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->unsignedBigInteger('brand_id')->nullable();
      $table->foreign('brand_id')->references('id')->on('brands');
    });
}
```

Create Category Interest:

```
enter code here:
     Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->unsignedBigInteger('brand_id')->nullable();
      $table->foreign('brand_id')->references('id')->on('brands');
    });
}
```

2 
    enter code here:

PDOStatement::execute()
      /Users/Ezequiel/Desktop/dandelion/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:458